# FreeRDP 2.0 in Windows is failing silently

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, github

Just downloaded the more recent binaries (static compilation) for Windows

from:
https://ci.freerdp.com/job/freerdp-nightly-windows/lastBuild/

Extracted to a folder and launch the executable: wfreerdp.exe

Nothing happens and the program exit silently...

1. Analyzed the exe.image with "DependencyWalker" and all seems OK
2. Analyzed it with Sysinternals "Process Explorer" and fails to load
3. Analyzed it with Sysinternals "Process Monitor" and it tries to load some DLL(s)...

Looked the site for additional downloads but no luck
Looked the site for documentation for Windows, also no luck
Looked the site wiki for more info, luckless...

Anybody that uses FreeRDC in Windows has a hint about the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is an older question, but I recently had this problem and this is what I found.

WFreeRDP doesn't redirect to STDOUT correctly on the Windows command line.  The workaround I found was to redirect to a text file, then use a text editor like Notepad++ that detects changes to a file.

For example:

wfreerdp.exe /v:servername /u:domain\user /p:password > output.txt

Comment: will try... thx...

Comment: If you install a "tee"-type tool (e.g., https://ritchielawrence.github.io/mtee/) then you can see the output without opening a file.  Use the command "wfreerdp.exe --help | mtee nul".